# Understanding equality $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(\theta)}{2 + \cos(\theta)}d\theta = \pi - \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2 + \cos(\theta)}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am reading an example and in the example there is a step where I just don't follow. It says that the following equality holds: $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(\theta)}{2 + \cos(\theta)}d\theta = \pi - \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2 + \cos(\theta)}.$$ I have not been able to figure out why it would hold. Have been trying to find some trig. identity that I might have forgotten but with no luck, and I thought maybe it was a variable change of some kind but I haven't gotten that to work either (and I can't think of any variable change that would lead me to that $\pi$ on the right-hand side). What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{2+\cos(\theta)}d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)+2-2}{2+\cos(\theta)}d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta-\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2d\theta}{2+\cos(\theta)}\right).
$$
Can you go from here?